# Change css for the current selected li when a is active

Tags: css, wordpress

So i have this menu, this is the structure:

```
<div id="menu-home">
    <ul>
        <li> a.active </li>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
               <li> a </li>
           </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What i need to access is that `<ul class="sub-menu">` when the a is active
Can someone point me to that?
I've used:

```
#menu-s a.active ul.sub-menuul {
        display:block;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of mark up is this? And what is up with your class names in the CSS?

Comment: WORDPRESS :( i don't know how to remove all this...so i have to deal with it!

Comment: Why did you write `#menu-s` and `ul.sub-menuul` when there are no such elements in your mark up?

Comment: When the 'a' is active do you actually have a class of 'active' on the li element?

Comment: your second `ul` should be nested into a `li` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a messed up post, but if I understand what do you want to ask, the example below will help you.

This should be your HTML:

```
<div id="menu-home">
   <ul>
     <li> 
       <a href="#"> a.active 
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li> sample </li>
         </ul>
       </a>
     </li>           
   </ul>
</div>
```

This should be your CSS:

```
#menu-home ul li a:active ul.sub-menu li {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

I added few changes to CSS, for you, to help you understand what's happening.

This is  the jsfiddle link with the demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/aWe3n/24/

Answer (score 0):

This is not how u give class it should be `<a href="#" class="active">Link</a>`